# if/else in php and echo html code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement, echo

In the following code, I'm checking that if I'm on my home page of the website, then I will shift the columns by an offset of 2 toward right and for all other pages I shouldn't have any offset. I'm trying to implement this but I'm getting an error. It would be great if you can give me a hint. Thanks!

```
    <?php if (is_front_page() ) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-8 la-content-inside col-md-offset-2">';
        while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="col-md-8 la-content-inside">';
        while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); }
    }
    ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: try changing `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` to `while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); }` And please describe the error

Comment: I think you are using ternary while and that is not ended. It should be like "while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); endwhile;"

Comment: My original code is: --->  <div class="col-md-8 la-content-inside">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
        
                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
   </div> -------------- I want to make this part of the code work only on other pages and not the home page. For homepage, I want a column offset of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are opening `while` block in `if` & `else` block & closing the `endwhile` after condition blocks.

try using

```
<?php  
if (is_front_page() ) {
    echo '<div class="col-md-8 la-content-inside col-md-offset-2">';
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
    endwhile; // end of the loop.
}else {
    echo '<div class="col-md-8 la-content-inside">';
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
    endwhile; // end of the loop. 
}
?>
```

Comment: isn't going to work because you while is formatted incorrectly

Comment: Answer has been updated, thanks @FerryKobus. I copy the code provided by questioner & forgot to remove the curly braces.

Comment: Your welcome @RaviKrishna. I'll be very greatful to you if you please give me a Vote up on my answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with cleaning up your code. I'm writing the code over several lines so it stays understandable for the one asking the question. (Yes, you could write it more efficient)

```
<?php
echo '<div class="col-md-8 la-content-inside';
// frontpage exception
if(is_front_page()) {
     echo ' col-md-offset-2';
}
echo '>';

while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

If this generates an error. Please copy paste the error as comment in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

try below short code.. will for you..

```
<div class="col-md-8 la-content-inside <?php echo (is_home() ? 'col-md-offset-2' : '' );?> ">
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
      get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
   endwhile; // end of the loop.
 ?>
 </div>
```

you need to user `is_home()` function.. for front page.